# converting hashmap to stringarray

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap, arrays, keyset

I am trying to convert a hashmap into an array, that I can put in a created string array. I however get java.lang. I have typeconverted my drinkar.keySet().toArray() to String[], but it will still not work.

```
public String[] receiveArrayList(){

String[] list = new String[0];

    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        drinkar = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) (ois.readObject());
        System.out.println(drinkar);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(drinkar.keySet().toArray()));
        list = (String[]) (drinkar.keySet().toArray());

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.println(list);
        }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drinkar.keySet().toArray()` returns `Object[]` not `String[]`

One of the way may be:

user [Collections.toArray(StringArry)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

(or)

Iterate through the `keySet` and add each element to array.

Comment: thanks, but i cant seem to get it right. i dont think i know how to iterate correctly.

Comment: while(it.hasNext()){
             String temp = it.next(); //then add temp to String array.
            }

Comment: is there a way to add strings to arrays? doesnt seem like it

Comment: arr[0]=temp; this will add temp at index 0

Comment: it didnt work, i still get nothing. but i tried another way. created an arraylist, added temp to the arraylist and it worked and i could print it easily. but when i tried to convert it to array, it gave me java.lang.

Answer (score 9):

Use [toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) as:

```
String[] list = drinkar.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

By giving an empty array as the argument, you tell `toArray` to create a new array of the same type for you that will be just of the correct size.

---

Just a note: If you can choose, it's usually more convenient (and safer) to work with collections such as `ArrayList` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

String st[]=hm.keySet().toArray(new String[hm.size()]);

Answer (score 0):

Another option is create `ArrayList<type>` and add elements and return `list.toArray()`. This is exactly what `toArray` does on `entryset` Can not type code since not front of desktop