# Extract String[] elements from a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

at my work I've got the following source code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Temporaer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List stringArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
        stringArrayList.add(fillStringArrayElement("a", "b"));
        stringArrayList.add(fillStringArrayElement("c", "d"));

        String[] listElement;

        /*
         * I'm stuck here, because I don't know what I have to do
         */

        System.out.println(listElement.length);
    }

    //Just a method to fill a list easily
    private static String[] fillStringArrayElement (String firstElem, String secondElem)
    {
        String[] stringArrayListElement = new String[2];
        stringArrayListElement[0] = firstElem;
        stringArrayListElement[1] = secondElem;
        return stringArrayListElement;
    }
}
```

My goal is it to extract each list item and work with those.

I tried to use the `toArray[T[])` method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077769/converting-hashmap-to-stringarray). Though it generates an `java.lang.ArrayStoreException`. **Note:** I cannot change the type of the list because the list is filled by an extern service. Maybe I have to convert the list first...

Can someone show me a way to achive my goal? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You should type your list: `List<String[]> stringArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Side note: you can just do `stringArrayList.add(new String[] {"a", "b"});` rather than using your method.

Comment: @Supericy yeah you'r right. Sometime lies the easiest things in front of the eyes. So +1

Comment: @Djon When I wrote this post I didn't realized that I worked under 1.4 . sorry for that.

Comment: I should have precised that this syntax only works for Java 7, my bad.

Comment: @Djon You mean Generics ?

Comment: The diamond inference, I thought that was what OP was talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Iterator` is an `interface` in java used to `iterate` over a `Collection` like `ArrayList` or other `Collection` framework classes. 
Before reading `ArrayList` make sure values are available using the `size()` method.

Here a sample working snippet for your problem.

```
    String [] myArray ;
    if (stringArrayList.size()>0){
        Iterator<String [] > i = stringArrayList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
                  myArray =  i.next();
                  for(String s : myArray)
                      System.out.println(s);
                }
                }

        }
```

Don't use `Raw ArrayList`, instead use `Generics`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    List<String[]> stringArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList<String[]>();
    stringArrayList.add(new String[]{"a", "b"});
    stringArrayList.add(new String[]{"c", "d"});

    //if you cant to convert the stringArrayList to an array:
    String[][] listElement = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[0][]);
    for (String[] inArr : listElement){
        for (String e : inArr){
            System.out.print(e + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Just a side question: Which conditions speak for to declare the target object as "String[][]"? I've never seen this before.

Comment: `stringArrayList` is a list of arrays of strings (`List<String[]>`); converting `stringArrayList` to an array returns an array of arrays of strings, thus `String[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] listElement;
```

Above statements is **incorrect** because you are keeping `arrays` in `list` so your `listElement` **must** contain `String[]` .

```
String [][] listElement
```

Something like below.

```
listElement=stringArrayList.toArray(new String[stringArrayList.size()][]);
```